# Map shared network folder as servername

Tags: windows, network-share, mappeddrive

We have an application that is regular deployment to live.
Of course we try to test it as much as possible before.
Many settings is stored in a ini-file

An example setting for a path

**Live**

```
AccountingSystemExportPath=\\org2000Appserv\UserFolders\Econet
```

**Test**

```
AccountingSystemExportPath=\\TestAppServ\Attracs\Peura\RC\UserFolders\Econet
```

So the problem is that setting is different in live and test.
What I want is a way to map a servername (\\Org2000AppServ in this case) to a shared network folder.

So something like

```
SUBST Org2000AppServ \\TestAppServ\Attracs\Peura\RC
```

If above command work I could have same setting to live and test and testing would be more reliable. Any hints ?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve...  Do you want to be able to switch quickly between Live and Test ini files and without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to have an identical INI file (including, e.g., `AccountingSystemExportPath=Org2000AppServ`) for both LIVE and TEST environments, yet have the folder specified in the INI file (`Org2000AppServ`) point to a different location, depending whether it is a TEST or LIVE server. Is that correct?

If that is indeed the case, you can do that with [MKLINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx), e.g.:

**LIVE** Server:

```
MKLINK /D C:\Org2000AppServ \\org2000Appserv\UserFolders\Econet
```

**TEST** Server:

```
MKLINK /D C:\Org2000AppServ \\TestAppServ\Attracs\Peura\RC\UserFolders\Econet
```

**INI File** on both servers:

```
AccountingSystemExportPath=C:\Org2000AppServ
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBST you can only mount the network shared drive to a physical drive which is having a physical drive letter. You requirement is to create a symbolic link for the path "TestAppServ\Attracs\Peura\RC" to "Org2000AppServ" and that is not possible using SUBST. Also I tried the requirement with nfs share and that too didn't work for the same.